# How can I merge my insert scripts with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, sql-insert

I have a (spring boot) project in IntelliJ Ultimate. There are two tables `Main` and `Extension` where every entry in `Main` has one corresponding entry in `Extension`, e.g.

`Main`

| main_id | main_col_a |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | lorem |
| 1 | ipsum |

`Extension`

| main_id | extension_col_a | extension_col_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | b | irrelevant |
| 1 | c | data |

Now I have merged the tables, so that `Main` consists of `main_id`,`main_col_a` and `extension_col_a` (and `Extension` is dropped). But for my many tests I have ~100 sql files with insert clauses that need to be merged as well, so I need to turn

```
INSERT INTO MAIN(MAIN_ID, MAIN_COL_A) VALUES
(0, 'lorem'),
(1, 'ipsum');

INSERT INTO EXTENSION(MAIN_ID, EXTENSION_COL_A, EXTENSION_COL_B) VALUES
(0, 'b', 'irrelevant'),
(1, 'c', 'data');
```

into

```
INSERT INTO MAIN(MAIN_ID, MAIN_COL_A) VALUES
(0, 'lorem', 'b'),
(1, 'ipsum', 'c');
```

in an automated way.

There is some variation such as alignment, but the inserts for `Extension` always follow those for `MAIN` and the ids are always in the same order.
I'm not worried about deleting the `Extension` table but about moving the column from `Extensions` to `Main`. I'm currently considering writing a python script but I'm wondering if it can maybe done easily with IntelliJ features. I know about multiple cursors, but there are too many files for that and for Macros I don't think they can be easily applied for the varying number of lines in the insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Replace in Files" with regex expressions.
Open `Edit` -> `Find` -> `Replace in Files...`

Create expressions based on this guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html#regex-syntax-reference

Here is something to get you started:

Find: `INSERT INTO MAIN\(MAIN_ID\, MAIN_COL_A\) VALUES[\s]*(\([\w'"]*, [\w'"]*, [\w'"]*\),)*[\s]*(\([\w'"]*\, [\w'"]*)\)([\w\W]*INSERT INTO EXTENSION\(main_id, extension_col_a, extension_col_b\) values)[\s]*\([\w'"]\, ([\w'"]*)\, [\w'"]*\)[,;]`

Replace:
`INSERT INTO MAIN\(MAIN_ID\, MAIN_COL_A\) VALUES\n$1\n$2, $4\)$3`

Use find&replace as many times as needed to merge the tables and then use it to edit the first line of the insert into main and delete the insert into extension.